# How Can I spawn a .URDF model in gazebo 1.3?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I want to know how to spawn a URDF model in gazebo 1.3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1099/how-can-i-spawn-a-.urdf-model-in-gazebo-1.3?/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-01-29**:
in ROS or standalone gazebo? Did you try rosrun gazebo spawn_model?

**Comment by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on 2013-01-30**:
Standalone gazebo @davinci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you have installed Gazebo from debian, then Gazebo should auto-magically import a URDF file. You can use the `gzfactory` command line tool.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elizabeth C](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/290/elizabeth-c/) on 2013-05-15**:
That would have been a very nice thing to document somewhere other than the answers site.